# standalone inside

Tags: tcolorbox, standalone, tcblisting

**The code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\tcbset{sidebyside}
 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcblisting}{
comment and listing,
pdf comment,
freeze pdf,
compilable listing,
run pdflatex,lefthand ratio=0.4,
}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\[1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\]
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

**shows as a page, not cropped to the equation**
[image]

So how can I produce "cropped" result of the code inside?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can't use `\[...\]` in `standalone`. For the rest, I cannot reproduce your output and get an image cropped as expected.

Comment: @egreg so there is no way to produce result of "inside" compilation bigger?

Comment: Maybe you have a `standalone.cfg` file in the same working directory?

Comment: @egreg I  added ```standalone.cfg```  with ```\standaloneconfig{margin=4}```, but nothing changed. No, I have not, I am trying the small code in another directory

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! You also need to pass the `crop` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `standalone.cfg` file in the same directory as your files.

The documentation is a bit scanty on the topic, but I discovered that

```
\standaloneconfig{margin=4}
```

isn't sufficient to get the desired result. You also need to pass the `crop` option *before* `margin`.

Besides, using `\[...\]` in such a `standalone` document isn't allowed.

#### File `standalone.cfg`

```
\standaloneconfig{crop,margin=4}
```

#### Example file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}

\tcbset{sidebyside}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcblisting}{
  comment and listing,
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
  lefthand ratio=0.4,
}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\)
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank You, but it is hard to see the final ```standalone``` result, so what should be added to fit it fully?

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh `comment style={scale=2}` to make it bigger

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, thank You, it works! Also I tried to add ```postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}``` in ```\tcbset```, but it doesn't work(, how can I make it possible?

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh It would be good if you'd ask a new question including a MWE. (and your curly braces seem wrong)